# Removing a row from a javascript dataset and carrying it over into another dataset?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dataset

Essentially, I have 2 datasets and a function. (The numbers after the name are stats, and are just placeholder but I need them to carry over exactly)

```
var randomIngredientsList = [["Bread", 1, 2], ["Water", 5, 2]]
var ingredients = [["Mustard", 2, 3]]
```

When I'm supposed to get a random ingredient, I want to carry over from `randomIngredientsList`, remove that specific part, and put it into `ingredients`.
There will also be different `randomIngredientsList`s with different tiers and stats so i need it to be able to differentiate them.

My function now looks something like this:

```
function generateRandomIngredient(nameOfArray){ 
        var randomValue = Math.floor(Math.random() * nameOfArray.length) //grabs a random number from 0-the length of the dataset
        console.log(randomValue)
            if(nameOfArray.length = 0){     // if ingredient  list is empty
            exploreLogger.unshift("You seem to have picked clean all the ingredients in this tier. Good job!"); //explorelogger is a log at the end of the screen, which shows events
            } else { //if it's not empty
    ingredients.push(nameOfArray[randomValue]) // add it to the ingredients list
    nameOfArray.splice(randomValue, 1) //remove the row from the dataset
            }
}
```

When it run it with `generateRandomIngredient(randomIngredientsList)` it deletes all objects in `randomIngredientsList` and adds an undefined value to `ingredients`. I don't know what to do, I've spent 2 hours on this issue and found nothing about it online. Thanks to anyone who provides any help or answers.

Comment: Show us a example what it will before and what after this action.

Comment: The `ingredients` list should be, for example, `[["Mustard", 2, 3]]` and afterwards if the randomvalue is 0, the `randomIngredientsList` would be `[["Water", 5, 2]]` and the `ingredients` would be `[["Mustard", 2, 3], ["Bread", 1, 2]]` since the value in 0th place in `randomIngredientsList` is `["Bread", 1, 2]`

Comment: in your `if`, you are assigning (`=`) instead of comparing (`===`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning `0` to the array's length instead of comparing.

```
if(nameOfArray.length = 0){
```

should be changed to

```
if(nameOfArray.length === 0)
```

Comment: How could I have made such a simple mistake... Thank you so much